# When to use Javascript decorators vs inheritance

Tags: javascript, decorator

I am learning how to use decorators in Javascript and am confused as to when its appropriate to use class inheritance vs decorators?

For instance the following uses decorators to add a method to a class. It also overwrites one of the decorated classes methods.

```
import $ from "jquery";

function write(msg) {
  $("#app").prepend(msg);
}

function clean(constructor) {
  return class extends constructor {
    foo() {
      write("<h1>from the Decorated class</h1>");
    }
    bar() {
      write("I haz bar");
    }
  };
}

@clean
class Hello {
  foo() {
    write("<h1>from the undecorated class</h1>");
  }
}

const h = new Hello();
h.();
```

AFAIK, with inheritance — if the parent and child classes have the same methods, it would be flipped: child would overwrite the parent. In a situation where I would NOT want this to happen, decorators would be the desired choice. Is that correct?

P.S.
I know decorators not officially in the language yet.

Comment: Your decorator example uses inheritance. It just changes the order (decorator result inherits `Hello` vs `Hello` inheriting another class). The main advantage of class decorators is you can apply multiple to a class. Also the decorator syntax isn't supported, but you could just call `clean` with the function call syntax: `const DecoratedHello = clean(Hello);`

I recommend not using either if you can avoid them.